# Does the emission of Larmour Radiation by an electron require additional force to be applied to achieve a given velocity?

Tags: electrons, acceleration, radiation

Accelerating a charge causes the emission of radiation, but I can't find a clear answer as to whether or not an electron loses kinetic energy as a result of this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula

In the case of cyclotron radiation, the answer seems to be yes, in that if you rotationally accelerate an electron, it will lose kinetic energy, which is why an electron will eventually run of out kinetic energy in a magnetic field:

https://cds.cern.ch/record/137995/files/p231.pdf

I can't see why the two cases would be any different, but I can't find a firm statement either way.

This is a pretty simple question, yet I can't find any clarity on the issue.

Comment: Is "Larmour radiation" a standard term? How would it be any different from any other radiation by a point charge? Isn't it just ... radiation? *Accelerating a charge causes the emission of radiation, but I can't find a clear answer as to whether or not an electron loses kinetic energy as a result of this* What about conservation of energy?

Comment: Accepted terminology distinguishes between (1) rotational acceleration, which is called cyclotron radiation, and (2) rectilinear acceleration, which is called Larmor radiation. Part of the reason I'm asking is because it's not clear to me how energy is conserved.